# Issue removing detached VHD from premium Azure Storage in portal

Tags: azure

I created a VM (Premium/DS3) and attached other premium disks that I no longer need. When I detach the disks from the VM and attempt to remove them from the Azure Portal I get the following error:

> Failed to delete storage blob

With very little detail:

Title: Failed to delete storage blob
Description: Failed to delete storage blob vhds/[vhdname].vhd
Status: Error

Is there something I need to do to delete the premium disks?

I've had this issue with regular disks in the new portal and I can go into the old portal and delete them just fine...however, premium disks can't be managed in the old portal apparently.

Comment: did you try again? Sometimes it takes a while to break the lease on blobs.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying since Thursday of last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Premium Storage cannot be managed inside of the old portal, you can delete the Premium disks by navigating to Old Portal -> Virtual Machines -> Disks and deleting the disk. Note: the name of the disk in the old portal and the name of your disk in the new portal DO NOT match, you'll need to match them by URL, this was not apparent until I spoke to Azure Support.